# Parsing till end of string and checking for end of line in java

Tags: java

I have the below contents from a .txt file stored into a string variable **actual_text**

1 1111 47

2 2222 92

3 3333 81

So now **actual_text** will have the value

1 1111 47

2 2222 92

3 3333 81

I'm trying to achieve two objectives from the below snippet

```
while(parse till end of string condition)      //parse till the end actual_text
        {
            if(end of line condition)     //checking for the "\n" string in actual_text
            {
                                  //random code 
            }
                }
```

Can anyone tell me how to do the parsing and checking the end of line in the above program.

Comment: Are you using Scanner, to read in the text, as you won't have the \n in actual_text if you are. If you are not, you should probably look at it as I think it would help you.

Comment: Is your goal to parse a text file line-by-line?

Comment: @ lins314159 Im not sure as to how to check the end of string condition but for end of line I know that it's actual_text.equals("\n")

Comment: @ lynxoid yes without using bufferedreader and readline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (String line : actual_text.split("\\n"))
{
     //process each line
}
```